# Cross domain jQuery $.ajax request fails for PUT (Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, put

I am doing cross domain requests via jQuery's `$.ajax` to access a RESTful PHP API.
In order to do so I have set the following headers in PHP:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 $code $status");
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
```

Using the types `GET` and `POST` works without problems. However when I do a `PUT` ajax call Firefox fails completely and shows `OPTIONS api.php` in the network tab of Firebug.
In Chrome the same thing happens first (`OPTION` request fails with message `Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.`) but Chrome follows up with the actual `PUT` request 
that actually works then.

**What is the reason for this behaviour?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently the browser first sends an `OPTIONS` request to find out if `PUT` (or `DELETE`) requests are allowed.
Since I had not allowed the `OPTIONS` method in `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` it failed and so did the `PUT` request after in Firefox.
Adding `OPTIONS` to `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` solved the problem:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS');
```